# Hide lines with zero values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following table generated by a pivot:

```
╔════════╦══╦══════════╦════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Line # ║  ║   Car    ║ Sold/Stock ║ Store 1 ║ Store 2 ║ Store 3 ║ Store 4 ║ Store 5 ║
╠════════╬══╬══════════╬════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║      1 ║  ║ BMW      ║ Sold       ║       5 ║       1 ║       0 ║       6 ║       4 ║
║      2 ║  ║ BMW      ║ Stock      ║       2 ║       0 ║       2 ║       3 ║       4 ║
║      3 ║  ║ Audi     ║ Sold       ║       3 ║       4 ║       5 ║       5 ║       8 ║
║      4 ║  ║ Audi     ║ Stock      ║       3 ║       1 ║       0 ║       0 ║       1 ║
║      5 ║  ║ Mercedes ║ Sold       ║       2 ║       0 ║       4 ║       5 ║       6 ║
║      6 ║  ║ Mercedes ║ Stock      ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║       0 ║
╚════════╩══╩══════════╩════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I want to hide the last row(6). Can it be done? I can't filter columns store 1 2 3 because i only want to filter when they all are blank. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The filters for the pivot table should show you all available values including "blank".  Set the drop-down to show multiple values, and turn that one off.

Comment: I have : Columns: Stores; Rows: Car, Values; Values: Sold,Stock; I can't apply any filters to the values

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in VBA, like so:

```
Dim hideMe as Bool
hideMe = True
For Each c In Range("E7:I7")
   If c.Value <> 0 Then
        hideMe = False
   End If
Next
Rows(7).EntireRow.Hidden = hideMe
```

The script assumes that you will want to hide the row (`hideMe = True`), and only decides otherwise if there is any cell in that range which is different from `0`.

Comment: i am not a specialist in VBA but it returns an error, user-defined type not defined. I used the code in a macro, inside Sub Macro2() <-> End Sub

Comment: Compile Error /break user-defined type not defined

Comment: I don't have Excel at the moment so I haven't tried it, i just wrote it. I will check when I have Excel available.